# WooCommerce product bulk edits

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have almost 800+ products in my site: https://www.hobbyelp.com.
It is a woocommerce site, but the problem is that I have to change many products to out-of-stock from time to time and it is very difficult to do one by one.

1. If I have a list of product Ids, is it possible for me to fire a SQL in the the database directly to bulk edit inventory?
2. or is there a plugin that can do the same for me?
3. I also tried using the import/export product feature of woocommerce, but for some reason, when I upload the product ID with a different information, it skips the import (as duplicate) instead of updating the product. Importing a CSV would be the best option, if it works.

thanks,

Comment: Look into WP All Import Pro. It meets your requirement for option 3. It's pretty robust and offers a ton of options for importing data.

Comment: Someone has written a similar function already  https://gist.github.com/codearachnid/5943589.  My question is why don't you use the Manage Stock option in WooCommerce so that it automatically sets a product as out of stock when it reaches 0 level??

Comment: @user1888257 First may be you could name your User and as a new user you could [get this StackOverFlow quick tour (20 seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) … **It's very easy to build a query** in a function where you will be able to **set an array of product Ids** and to **bulk change the product stock**. Now in database you have many things that you can update depending on your product settings. What do yo want to update exactly (you should look in `wp_postmeta` table)?